# there is no 10-master.conf file in my centos5.1

Tags: configuration-files, centos5, dovecot

I'am using some toturials on dovecot configuration . in those tutorials explained about a 10-master.conf file in /etc/dovecot/conf.d  but in my centos I just have a /etc/dovecot.conf file 
could any one help ?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 5 ships dovecot **1 version** if I am correct, and the tutorials may be related to version 2.

Dovecot 1 has one single configuration file, `/etc/dovecot.conf`, that stores everything. You can find common `10-master.conf` content, like `service` sections, in `/etc/dovecot.conf`.

Look at the official [wiki page](http://wiki1.dovecot.org/FrontPage) in order to get better information about dovecot 1.